# Xcode: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVPlayer"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to use `AVPlayer` in my app, i made a test application and it works perfectly, but then when i tried to implement the same `AVPlayer` in my real app it crashes with these two errors :

[image: Xcode ScreenShot]

This is LiveViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface LiveViewController : UIViewController<AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVPlayer *audioPlayer;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *playPauseBtn;
- (IBAction)playAudio:(id)sender;
@end
```

And this is LiveViewController.m:

```
#import "LiveViewController.h"

@interface LiveViewController ()

@end

@implementation LiveViewController
NSURL *urlStream;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    NSString *urlAddress = @"http://198.178.123.23:8662/stream/1/;listen.mp3";
    urlStream = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    self.audioPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:urlStream];
    
    NSError *error;
    
    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error in audioPlayer: %@",
              [error localizedDescription]);
    } else {
        [_audioPlayer prepareForInterfaceBuilder];
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)playAudio:(id)sender {
    if(self.audioPlayer.rate > 0 && self.audioPlayer.error == nil){
        [self.audioPlayer pause];
        NSLog(@"Hello there, trying to stop playing!");
        [self.playPauseBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play_button"]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }else{
        self.audioPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:urlStream];
        [self.audioPlayer play];
        NSLog(@"Hello there, trying to play!");
        [self.playPauseBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause_button"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}

-(void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:
(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
}

-(void)audioPlayerDecodeErrorDidOccur:
(AVAudioPlayer *)player error:(NSError *)error
{
}

-(void)audioPlayerBeginInterruption:(AVAudioPlayer *)player
{
}

-(void)audioPlayerEndInterruption:(AVAudioPlayer *)player
{
}

@end
```

What are these errors and how can i fix them ?

**NOTE:** i searched for those errors and didn't find a solution.

Comment: Have you added AVFoundation.framework to your project's build phases?

Comment: @AlexanderTkachenko i imported it in the header file, isn't that enough ?

Comment: No, Please, check if it's added in build phases.

Comment: you're right, i forgot to look for that, it worked :)

Comment: Great:) Good luck to you with AVFoundation)

Answer (score 5):

**Solution**: add `AVFoundation.framework` to your build phases in your project.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Just add `AVKit.framework` in Link Binary With Libraries from Build Phase

Go to >> Build phases. >>  Link Binary With Libraries >> Add AVKit.framework

Answer (score 0):

if you are facing issue with AVAudioEngine, but same error this will solve it for you.

Go to >> Build phases. >> Link Binary With Libraries >> Add AVFoundation.framework,AVFAudio.framework